# How to remove / clear all local database in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have *React Native* app with *SQL* database. I want to clear all local data at a certain place (for example: after log out I want to clear all the local database). I have multiple tables so I am not sure if there is any particular way to **clear all data** in one go.

i am using React Native SQLite Storage

Please suggest the best way to delete all local databases.

Comment: Did you use any 3rd-party lib, like `react-native-sqlite-storage` for SQL database?

Comment: @RYZheng Thanks for reply...Yes i am using react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this. You can list out all the tables and then discard tables you do not want to reset and then run the delete command.

```
let [results] = await this.db.executeSql('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" ORDER BY name');
var len = results.rows.length;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  let tableName = results.rows.item(i).name;
  if (tableName !== 'sqlite_sequence' && tableName !== 'android_metadata') {
      await this.db.executeSql(`DELETE FROM ${results.rows.item(i).name}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help..but i am getting error like undefined not an object (evaluating s.db.executeSql)

Comment: You should replace ```this.db``` with your db instance

Comment: sorry i did not understand ..i am very much new to React Native

Comment: Could you please post your code of initializing of SQLite database?